# Easy Localization: Localization key [...] not found

Tags: android-studio, flutter, localization

I am using easy_localization: ^2.3.3 in a flutter project with CSV loader. When I build it is not able to find keys and it gives "Easy Localization: Localization key [...] not found". Any ideas why is this happening?

```
runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', ''),
      Locale('it', ''),
      Locale('es', ''),
      Locale('de', ''),
      Locale('fr', ''),
      Locale('pt', ''),
    ],
    path: 'resources/langs/langs.csv',
    fallbackLocale: Locale('en', ''),
    saveLocale: false,
    useOnlyLangCode: true,
    assetLoader: CsvAssetLoader(),
    child: MyApp(status),
  ));
}
```

Comment: might be related to this bug: https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/issues/205

Comment: Have you done the other installation steps?
- Create folder and add translation files
- Declare your assets localization directory in pubspec.yaml
- etc.
https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization

Comment: I have, I found the solution though. answering right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution looking at this bug: https://github.com/aissat/easy_localization/issues/190#

I added the following:

```
dependencies:
  easy_localization_loader:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/aissat/easy_localization_loader.git
      ref: overman-dev
```

then I did a

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

and also changed the code into this

```
runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en'),
      Locale('it'),
      Locale('es'),
      Locale('de'),
      Locale('fr'),
      Locale('pt'),
    ],
    path: 'resources/langs/langs.csv',
    fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
    saveLocale: false,
    useOnlyLangCode: true,
    assetLoader: CsvAssetLoader(),
    child: MyApp(status),
  ));
```

It worked.

Comment: Kindly share your `langs.csv` file which has 2-3 keywords with translated words. Thanks

Comment: Your above suggested solution worked. I was trying with `Locale('en_US')` because I have used it in my old project, this may be possible new version of this package only supports `Locale('en')`. Thanks dear.

Answer (score 41):

Also this error can be happen for not setting the material app; I mean, I got same error for forgeting the add these lines to my material app;

```
MaterialApp(
    locale: context.locale,
    supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
    localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
  ),
```

and my problem solved !

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is important to note, in case you wrapped the EasyLocalization widget around the MaterialApp widget, that you also wrap the MaterialApp with a Builder widget so the context gets updated with the easy localization data correctly

Answer (score 5):

You need to import `import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';`

And add in your MaterialApp :

```
locale: context.locale,
supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
```